# Book Identification: Stuck in a Store after Closing

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

It's a choose your own adventure book, where you are stuck in a department store after closing and have to escape. Toys come to life etc...

Published in the UK, probably else where. I do know it's not a [Fighting Fantasy](http://www.fightingfantasycollector.co.uk/book_covers.htm) book.

This would have been mid-late 1980s, but the book could be earlier than that.

Comment: Any idea how long ago you read it?  In the wake of Goosebumps, the 'Choose your own nightmare' series was written; I haven't read it, but 'The Toy Shop of Terror by Laban Carrick Hill, 1997' *might* fit.. Not enough detail to know.  Try wikipedia's [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books) and see if any names look familiar...

Comment: @KeithHWeston It would have been mid to late 80s at a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it may be this one:

http://books.google.com/books/about/Nightmare_store.html?id=73P3ItjZ3a4C

I haven't read it though, so I can't confirm details. Keith's suggestion also seems valid (same series too), so it's going to be difficult to figure out unless someone who's actually read the titles pipes up.

Comment: Thanks! It *sounds* right, I'll do some google-fu and check the details when I get home.

Comment: Yes, that's it. This is a better link - I recognised the cover - http://www.gamebooks.org/show_item.php?id=1911